# Any reason not to skiprearm when deploying Win7?

Tags: windows-7, deployment, licensing, wds

If you always intend to deploy within your organization, and license windows with KMS, is there ever a reason not to include skiprearm=1 in your various unattend files?

Seems to let me get more use out of my images.

Comment: This is a system administration question and belongs on [sf].  Voting to close and migrate.

Answer (score 1):

Rearming Windows allows you to reset the grace period for activation on your clients.  Since you're using KMS, there is no need for a grace period since the machine will automatically activate as soon as the KMS server is found.

In fact, you absolutely should always use `skiprearm=1` whenever you sysprep your images, because you are limited to three rearms.

If you attempt to rearm a fourth time, you will get an [error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929828). Thus, you can no longer make changes to this particular image and will need to start fresh. This can be a problem if you like to periodically roll updates into your OS image (like we do).

Comment: You can add updates to offline images with `DISM`. You won't need to rearm or recapture, because you do it to the offline .wim. Just food for thought.